# Binding data to the treeview consisting of single property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview

I want to bind data to a treeview consisting only single property of TreeViewItem type. I hope my question is very specific to the reader. Kindly provide me with the solution. And i don't want to bind data something like this: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/pavely/2014/07/12/data-binding-for-a-wpf-treeview/

Currenty what I am doing is something like this and it is working fine:

```
TreeView x:Name="tvServers" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" BorderThickness="0,0,0,0" AllowDrop="True"  ItemsSource="{Binding ConnectedServerNodes,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}".
```

I want to display the content in the hierarchical manner.

Comment: "Currenty what I am doing is something like this and it is working fine" so what is the problem?
Do you have hierarchical data for displaying? Can you post it?

Comment: <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="CheckBoxItemTemplate" ItemsSource="{Binding ConnectedServerNodes,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <CheckBox Focusable="False" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding TreeViewItem, Mode=OneTime}" Margin="2;0"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

Comment: <TreeView x:Name="tvServers" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" BorderThickness="0,0,0,0" AllowDrop="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=OneTime}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CheckBoxItemTemplate}">

Comment: I want to achieve data binding using the above fashion. Important points 1) data should be bind to only one property. 2) I want to add checkboxes for each node of the tree structure. 3) I Want to display data in hierarchical manner.